# What happened to your job?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cipher

It is 8 am and you are at work, solving a puzzle on Puzzling StackExchange when you get an email from your boss.
The email is below:

```
 ​ ​​  ​ ​​ ​​​​ ​​​ ​ ​  ​      ​​    ​ ​​​  ​  ​​  ​ ​  ​      ​​  ​​  ​​ ​  ​ ​​​  ​  ​​  ​ ​ ​​  ​    ​      ​​  ​​  ​​ ​​​​ ​​​  ​   ​      ​​​  ​​ ​​​     ​​  ​ ​ ​​ ​​​  ​​  ​   ​​ ​  ​ ​​ ​​​  ​​  ​​​  ​      ​​​ ​   ​​ ​​​​  ​      ​​ ​​ ​ ​​​ ​ ​ ​​   ​​ ​​ ​     ​      ​​​ ​   ​​ ​  ​ ​​ ​​ ​ ​​  ​ ​  ​      ​​ ​​​​ ​​ ​​​   ​      ​​​     ​​​ ​ ​ ​​​​ ​  ​​​​ ​  ​​ ​​   ​​ ​  ​ ​​ ​​​  ​​  ​​​  ​ ​​​  ​​​  ​​ ​​​ ​   ​​    ​ ​​   ​​ ​​ ​ ​​ ​​  ​ ​ ​​​​    ​​   ​​ ​​ ​    ​​    ​ ​​ ​​​  ​​  ​​​ ​​  ​ ​  ​      ​​    ​ ​​ ​​​  ​​  ​    ​      ​​ ​​​  ​​ ​​​​ ​​​ ​    ​      ​​​ ​​​ ​​ ​​​​ ​​​  ​  ​​ ​ ​​ ​​ ​  ​ ​​ ​​​  ​​  ​​​  ​    ​
```

***What does the email say?***

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The e-mail reads

> You are fired for spending to much time on puzzling.stackexchange and not working!

Explanation

> Code block contains spaces and zero-width spaces. Take every 8 characters, treat normal spaces as `0` and zero-width spaces as `1`, convert with ASCII.